# Вывод текста на canvas в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать ввод/вывод текста на канву,
как это сделано в новом `Paint` в `Windows7`, с возможностью редактировать текст
изменять шрифт и тд. Или, как написать компонент на подобие `RichEdit`, но 
с возможностью делать его прозрачным и выводом текста из него на канву.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно так, выводить текст на канву мне не приходилось, конечно, алгоритм придумать могу, но пока, я думаю, что этот код поможет: я однажды на курсач графический редактор писал, там выводил текст по такому алгоритму:

1. Выбрать кнопку "Текст", а затем нажать на нужном месте в Image;
2. Затем вывожу форму-мини-редактор текста, где нужно ввести текст;
3. Далее вводим текст и настраиваем: шрифт, цвет, угол наклона и т. п. или жмём отмена;
4. Жмём на кнопку - текст такой как нужно.

Код процедуры:

```
procedure TGraphEditorForm.ImageEditMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
Var
  OldBkFontColor: TColorRef; // цвет шрифта
  OldBkBGColor: TColorRef; // цвет под текстом
  OldBkMode: Integer;
begin

    // ...................... //

If (SpeedButtonText.Down) Then
    Begin
      ModRes:=TextForm.ShowModal; // вызываю форму для набора текста
      SpeedButtonText.Down:=False; // утопил кнопку на главной форме
      If (ModRes=mrCancel) Then // если отмена, то
        Begin
          MessageBox(0,
            PChar('Добавление текста отменено.'),
            PChar('Графический редактор'),
            MB_OK Or MB_ICONINFORMATION Or MB_APPLMODAL Or MB_TOPMOST);
          SpeedButtonText.Down:=False;
        End
      Else // иначе: добавляю текст
        Begin
          ImagePicture.Canvas.Font:=TextForm.FontDialog.Font; // устанавливаю шрифт
          If (TextForm.ColorDialog.Color<>clWhite) Then // если цвет под текстом не белый
            Begin
              OldBkFontColor:=SetTextColor(ImagePicture.Canvas.Handle,
                TextForm.FontDialog.Font.Color); // устанавливаю цвет текста и запоминаю цвет шрифта
              OldBkBGColor:=SetBkColor(ImagePicture.Canvas.Handle,
                TextForm.ColorDialog.Color); // устанавливаю цвет под текстом и запоминаю старый
              OldBkMode:=SetBkMode(ImagePicture.Canvas.Handle, OPAQUE); // режим рисования (установил новый и запомнил старый)
              CanvasSetAngle(ImagePicture.Canvas, TextForm.SpinEditAngle.Value); // устанавливаю угол вывода текста
              ImagePicture.Canvas.TextOut(X, Y, TextForm.LabeledEdit.Text); // вывожу сам текст
              (* возвращаю старые настройки, установленные ранее *)
              SetBkMode(ImagePicture.Canvas.Handle, OldBkMode);
              SetBkColor(ImagePicture.Canvas.Handle, OldBkBGColor);
              SetTextColor(ImagePicture.Canvas.Handle, OldBkFontColor);
            End
          Else
            Begin
              CanvasSetAngle(ImagePicture.Canvas, TextForm.SpinEditAngle.Value); // устанавливаю угол вывода текста
              ImagePicture.Canvas.TextOut(X, Y, TextForm.LabeledEdit.Text); // устанавливаю угол вывода текста
            End;
        End;
      End;

      // ...................... //

end;
```

Должен сказать, что это ещё не всё, что можно делать со шрифтом в графическом режиме: где-то (не помню точно где, наверное в большой базе знай по Делфи) видел, что можно изменять жирность, высоту и что-то ещё у шрифта.

А нечто подобное, я полагаю, можно сделать так:

1. На обработчике OnMouseMove для Image очертить рамку для текста (создать какой-нибудь флаг и присвоить ему истина);
2. По событию нажатия клавиши писать в неё текст (если флаг = истина), если клавиша = Enter закончить ввод (присвоить флагу ложь и зарисовать рамку, но чтобы рамка стёрлась корректно требуется 2 компонента Image: на одном всё рисуем и выделяем (он должен быть прозрачным (Transparent=True, цвет прозрачности - по умолчанию - самая первая нижняя точка компонента Image))).
    Попробую сделать, но ничего пока не обещаю.

Вроде бы получилось нечто подобное (типа прозрачного Мемо-поля (RichEdit вместо Memo тоже пойдёт)). Сразу скажу, что есть один минус: нельзя изменять размеры мышкой (можно подумать как сделать, но мне некогда).

Идея такова:

1. Создаем проект кидаем 2 компонента Image (первый на другой) так, чтобы у них были одинаковые размеры и один лежал точно под другим, ну и кнопку SpeedButton (AllowAllUp=True, GroupIndex=(не нуль)).
2. Добавляем в проект форму, на которую и кидаем Memo или RichEdit.
3. Растягиваем эти компоненты на всю форму (Align=alClient).
4. У формы устанавливаем свойство Transparent=true и TransparentColor выбираем любой цвет (но не тот, которого может быть шрифт, хотя программно тоже можно изменить, если ,конечно, нужно).
5. У компонента RichEdit или Memo цвет фона ставим такой, как и TransparentColor формы.

С разработкой форм можно покончить, - приступаем к кодированию (опишу вкратце):

1. Выделяем прямоугольную область обработчиком OnMouseMove компонента Image.
2. Затем на обработчике OnMouseUp показываем нашу вторую форму в ней.
3. Пишем текст, закрываем нажатием Enter.

Дальше, надеюсь, в коде всё будет понятно.

КОД главной формы (у другой ничего руками писать не нужно, только свойства настроить!):

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  StrMas: Array[0..199] Of ShortString;
  TextInImage, AllText: String;
  StartX, StartY, OldX, OldY, Wdt, Hgt, TextX, TextY, LineInd: Integer;
  Drag, DragShape: Boolean;

implementation

uses TextEditorUnit;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OldX:=0;
  OldY:=0;
  StartX:=0;
  StartY:=0;
  AllText:='';
  TextInImage:='';
  Image.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
  Image.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height));
  ImagePic.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
  ImagePic.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, ImagePic.Width, ImagePic.Height));
  ImagePic.Canvas.Font:=FontDialog.Font;
end;

procedure TForm1.ImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
// устанавливаю параметры
  If (SpeedButtonText.Down) Then
    Begin
      StartX:=X;
      StartY:=Y;
      Drag:=True;
      TextInImage:='';
    End;
end;

procedure TForm1.ImageMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  If Not(SpeedButtonText.Down) Then Exit;
  If Not(Drag) Then Exit;

  With Image.Canvas Do
    Begin
      // закрашиваю область
      Pen.Color:=clWhite;
      Pen.Style:=psSolid;
      Rectangle(StartX, StartY, OldX, OldY);
      // перерисовываю область
      Pen.Color:=clFuchsia;
      Pen.Style:=psDash;
      Rectangle(StartX, StartY, X, Y);
    End;
  // изменяю старые координаты
  OldX:=X;
  OldY:=Y;
end;
```

Продолжение кода

```
procedure TForm1.ImageMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
Var
  i, N, mr, OldBkMode: Integer;
  Str: String;
begin
  If Not (SpeedButtonText.Down) Then Exit;
  // сбрасываю параметры
  Drag:=False;
  Wdt:=Abs(StartX-OldX);
  Hgt:=Abs(StartY-OldY);
  TextX:=StartX;
  TextY:=StartY;
  SpeedButtonText.Down:=False;

  // устанавливаю форму в выделенную рамку
  If (StartX<OldX) Then
    TextEditorForm.Left:=StartX+Image.Left+ScrollBox.Left+Form1.Left+3
  Else
    TextEditorForm.Left:=OldX+Image.Left+ScrollBox.Left+Form1.Left+3;
  If (StartY<OldY) Then
    TextEditorForm.Top:=StartY+Image.Top+ScrollBox.Top+Form1.Top+22
  Else
    TextEditorForm.Top:=OldY+Image.Top+ScrollBox.Top+Form1.Top+22;
  // подгоняю размер формы
  TextEditorForm.Width:=Wdt+4;
  TextEditorForm.Height:=Hgt+4;

  // P.S. константные значения могут различаться, т. к. это пиксели

  mr:=TextEditorForm.ShowModal; // показываю форму

  N:=TextEditorForm.Memo.Lines.Count-1; // кол-во введённых строк

  // закрашиваю область
  With Image.Canvas Do
    Begin
      Pen.Color:=clWhite;
      Pen.Style:=psSolid;
      Rectangle(StartX, StartY, OldX, OldY);
    End;

    ImagePic.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Font:=FontDialog.Font;
  // OldBkMode:=SetBkMode(ImagePic.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
   // Закомментированные процедуры работают только в цикле почему-то...
   // Так не прокатывает

   With ImagePic.Canvas Do
    Begin
    // Построчно вывожу текст
      For i:=0 To N Do
        Begin
          Str:=TextEditorForm.Memo.Lines.Strings[i];
          OldBkMode:=SetBkMode(ImagePic.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
          TextOut(StartX, StartY, Str);
          SetBkMode(ImagePic.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, OldBkMode);
          StartY:=StartY+TextHeight(Str)+2;
        End;
    End;

  // SetBkMode(ImagePic.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, OldBkMode);
  TextEditorForm.Memo.Lines.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonFontClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If Not(FontDialog.Execute) Then Exit;

  TextEditorForm.Memo.Font:=FontDialog.Font;
  Image.Canvas.Font:=FontDialog.Font;
  ImagePic.Canvas.Font:=FontDialog.Font;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonOpenImageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If Not(OpenPictureDialog.Execute) Then Exit;

  ImagePic.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog.FileName);
  Image.Width:=ImagePic.Width;
  Image.Height:=ImagePic.Height;
end;

end.
```

**Если что-то не понятно, могу исходник прислать на E-mail.**

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить таким образом:

1. Обработав событие MouseClick на Image, при клике запоминаем позицию, где кликнули (X1, Y1)
2. Далее обработать событие MouseButtonDown (вроде), рисуем рамку от X1,Y1 до текущего положения мыши, ну и запоминаем конечно X2, Y2
3. Обработать событие MouseButtonUp, т.е. когда отпустили кнопку, то создаем элемент RichEdit в X1, Y1, размеры устанавливаем до X2, Y2, свойство рамки ставим - отсутствует, И фокус на него.
4. Для созданного RichEdit, обрабатываем событие выхода из него, т.е когда переключаемся на канвас, то значение из RichEdit записываем в переменную string, после чего выводим эту переменную функцией Canvas TextOut в X1,Y1, ну или в центре прямоугольника от X1,Y1 до X2,Y2

Делфи сейчас не стоит ,поэтому не могу привести пример) Но логика вроде такая) Творите)

Answer (score 0):

Вывод текста на канву

```
...canvas.textout(x,y,text)
```

http://www.beluch.ru/progr/100comp/3_2.htm

Answer (score 0):

Вот, к примеру, текст из `Edit'a` будет на картинке `Image1` чёрного цвета и прозрачным, то есть фона не будет.

```
Image1.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
Image1.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
Image1.Canvas.TextOut(5,5,Edit1.text);
```